# Is Class Course from salesforce.com, a compulsion for ADM201 certification ?

Tags: administration, unit-test, user-admin, certification

Do i have to compulsorily take the instructor led or classroom training classes for any of the salesforce.com ADM certifications. I am willing to self study & complete the certification within 60 days from now. Please Guide me

Comment: No. You don't need to take any class room training for any Salesforce Certificate.

Comment: @PramodKumar You should add that as an answer so it can be accepted before someone steals your rep!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You don't need to take any class room training for any Salesforce Certificate

Answer (score 4):

ADM201 is the name of the training course.

The Certfication is called Salesforce.com Certified Administrator.

The training courses are not a pre requisite for any of the certifications, however they do help if you're starting afresh.

The Administrator Certification is a pre requisite for the Advanced Admin and Cloud Consulant Certifications.

The Developer Ceritification is a pre requisite for the Advanced Developer and Technical Architect Certifications.

You need to maintain your certification credentials by taking maintenance release exams (one for each release) - however you just need to take these for the Administrator and Developer Certifications.